# Y axis out of plotting region with barplot() in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm having problems getting the y axis on a horizontal barplot() within the plotting region. See this example, I thought that using ylim and/or yaxp would stop this going off the plotting region, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried to reproduce the set up I've got:

```
x <- matrix(abs(rnorm(34)), nrow = 34, ncol = 3)
rownames(x) <- c(seq(0,6600,200))
barplot(x[,3], horiz=TRUE, space = 0.4, main = "Title", las=1, cex.names=0.8, ylab="y label")
```

But the axis goes of the plotting region if I add ylim:

```
barplot(x[,3], horiz=TRUE, space = 0.4, ylim = c(0,25), yaxp=c(0,25,1), main = "Title", las=1, cex.names=0.8, ylab="y label")
```

Comment: Could you provide some more detail as to what you're trying to do here? Setting the ylim=c(0,50) will ensure that everything stays in the plot window. Is that your question though?

Comment: Thanks, but see comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to forget about ylim when using barplot and instead just send the desired plotting range in the data:

```
barplot(x[1:25,3], horiz=TRUE,  space = 0.4,  yaxp=c(0,25,1), main = "Title", las=1,  
          cex.names=0.8, ylab="y label")
```

Also note that indexing in R starts at 1 and not at 0 as it might in some other languages.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks. btw out of curiosity does the ylim in barplot behave differently to other plots?

Comment: It surely seemed to exhibit "unexpected" behavior to me.

Answer (score 5):

For some (strange?) reason, `barplot` has `xpd = TRUE` by default, setting this to false will cause it to clip like most plot functions:

```
barplot(x[,3], horiz=TRUE, space = 0.4, ylim = c(0,25), yaxp=c(0,25,1),
        main = "Title", las = 1, cex.names = 0.8, ylab = "y label", xpd = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for these answers, however, to be clearer, instead of altering my data set, I want to limit the plot to the first 25 bars in this case. If I use xpd=F, as in above, then the plot is clipped after the first 18.5 bars and doesn't seem to take ylim into account.